# how to create a pure browser/javascript search engine for a bunch of static files?

Tags: javascript, python, full-text-search, search-engine

I was wondering if there exists some kind of indexer (in python language for exemple) that would take a bunch of html files and create an index in javascript.

In the solution, these javascript files would then be used to create a pure browser search engine.

Jerome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another very simple option is
http://dentedreality.com.au/projects/jssearch/

Answer (score 1):

A bit old and not in python:
http://jssindex.sourceforge.net/

Comment: thanks ; I saw this one but it is indeed a bit old and not working on windows where the generator should be installed.

Comment: You could have a go yourself in writing a primitive version. Shouldn't be super difficult.

Comment: you're right. Optimization of the index could take some time though. I am going to wait a little to see if someone comes up with the unicon ! Thx.